# how to run loop for php array in javascript( google graph api)

Tags: javascript, php, graph

how to run loop for php array in javascript( google graph api) i have x and y values in seprate php array and i am printing it like below.

```
   google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
   google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

  ['x', 'y'],
  <?php   

for($i=1;$i<1000;$i++)
 {
  ?>
      [<?php echo $x[$i]; ?>,<?php echo $y[$i]; ?>],


  <?php } ?>

 ]);

var options = {
  title: 'CGR plot',
  hAxis: {title: '(0,0)A (800,0) T', minValue: 0, maxValue: 800},
  vAxis: {title: '(800,800)G ;(0,800)C', minValue: 0, maxValue: 800},
  legend: 'none',
  pointSize: 1,
        };

var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

chart.draw(data, options);
 }
  </script>

    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 800px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

and it is working fine ...but here loop is runnning for 1000 times and try to run it according to array size using sizeof($x) or count($x). but it is not working. do u have any suggestion for this

Comment: `for($i=1;$i<1000;$i++)` makes loop running 1000 times, instead put `for($i=1;$i<count($x);$i++)`

Comment: cant you just use for($i=1;$i<count($x);$i++) ?

Comment: you beat me to it by second :)

Comment: P.S. array indexing starts from '0' ..

Comment: that's what i wrote , if i am using count or sizeof then it is not working.  i.e  for($i=0;$i<count($x);$i++)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) instead of looping though the array

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

in this case:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'y'], 
    <?php echo json_encode(array($x, $y)) ?>
]);
```

**Addition:**

One way to combine the arrays would be to use array_map:

```
$x =  array(1,3,5);
$y = array(2,4,6);

$combined = array_map(function($v, $k) use ($y) {
  return array($v, $y[$k]);
}, $x, array_keys($x));

// prepend the array with headers
array_unshift($combined, array('x', 'y'));

echo json_encode( $combined );  // [["x","y"],[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
```

For PHP which is older than 5.3:

```
function combine_array_element($v, $k) {
    global $y;
    return array($v, $y[$k]);
}    
$combined = array_map(combine_array_element, $x, array_keys($x));
```

Comment: i am new to javascript so i donot have much idea about it, could you please explain it in little detail or provide me link for documentation

Comment: JSON is a data format used to pass data around on the web. Since JSON is a subset of Javascript any valid JSON is valid javascript. To make it real simple - `json_encode` can take a php array and output javascript.

Comment: i wrote it like below in code but didn't work.                           var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          
              ['x', 'y'],
 
              [<?php echo json_encode(array($x,$y)) ?>],
             ]);

Comment: okay got the problem...its printing whole x array first n then whole y array.                                                  [["700","750","600"],["300","550","400"]]

each array has three element in this case:::first is whole x array 
and second one is whole y array


Can we print it like :

[["700","300"],
 ["750","550"],
 ["600","400"]
]                                                                          [first element of array x,first element of array y]

Comment: Sorry I guess I should have read though the reference more carefully. I edited my answer - should now give `[["label x","label y"],[x1,y1],[x2,y2]...]` as per the example on https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/#assortedmethods